# Setting up cookie expiration date

Tags: javascript, cookies

Sorry if this has been asked many times, I'm just starting to learn javascript. I currently have this simple javascript function, I've tried the examples in the web for setting up cookie expiration but the script is not working when I do.

I basically want to set a cookie and make its expiration to 30 days after it has been setup. Here's my function:

```
function viewThumbList(){
  document.cookie="list=thumblist; path=/";
  location.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass param "expires" and set it equal to date.

```
// +1 day since now
var date = new Date;
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
```

So you should use it like :

```
var date = new Date;
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 30);
function viewThumbList(){
  document.cookie="expires="+date+"; list=thumblist; path=/";
  location.reload();
}
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you. But I wonder if I can also make a function to delete the cookie. How should I delete a cookie using a funciton in javascript?

Comment: To delete cookie, you should first give it a 'name' param. Like document.cookie="expires="+date+"; list=thumblist; name=yourname; path=/"; And to delete, you should then pass the -1 value to the 'expires' param. Like document.cookie="expires=-1; list=thumblist; name=yourname; path=/";

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an `expires` section to the cookie string. For example:

```
expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC
```

So your whole cookie string would read:

```
document.cookie="list=thumblist; path=/; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC";
```

You just have to get the date that you want:

```
var nextMonth = new Date();
nextMonth.setDate(nextMonth.getDate() + 30);
var expiresDate = nextMonth.toString();
document.cookie = "list=thumblinst; path=/; expires=" + expiresDate;
```